# Iterate and append list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists in Python and I want to index it with keys numbers in a dictionary.

AST = ['AGENDA'],["WOMEN'S STATUS", 'TREATIES',
  'SIGNATURES, ACCESSIONS, RATIFICATIONS',
  'RESERVATIONS AND DECLARATIONS',
  'GENDER DISCRIMINATION'], ['ELECTION OF MEMBERS',
  'BIOGRAPHY'], [ "WOMEN'S RIGHTS",
  "WOMEN'S STATUS",
  'PERIODIC REPORTS']"

if I iterate over the lists, I get separate lists, as normal, but when I want to add them to a dictionary. Python is only showing the last list. `enter code here`

```
0: [["WOMEN'S RIGHTS", "WOMEN'S STATUS", 'PERIODIC REPORTS']],
1: [["WOMEN'S RIGHTS", "WOMEN'S STATUS", 'PERIODIC REPORTS']],
2: [["WOMEN'S RIGHTS", "WOMEN'S STATUS", 'PERIODIC REPORTS']],
3: [["WOMEN'S RIGHTS", "WOMEN'S STATUS", 'PERIODIC REPORTS']]}
```

How to do this correclty in Python to have a structure like this one?

```
1: ['AGENDA']
2: ["WOMEN'S STATUS", 'TREATIES', 'SIGNATURES, ACCESSIONS,
    RATIFICATIONS', 'RESERVATIONS AND DECLARATIONS', 'GENDER 
    DISCRIMINATION']
3: ['ELECTION OF MEMBERS', 'BIOGRAPHY']
4: ["WOMEN'S RIGHTS", "WOMEN'S STATUS", 'PERIODIC REPORTS']
```

```py
for t in AST:
    print (t)
```

```py
new_dict = {new_list: t for new_list in range(len(AST))} 
print(new_dict)
```

thre result is only showing the last list. Ho

Comment: your problem ist that `t` has always the same value, which is the last list item, since you use `t` as iterator in the first loop. This is actually not required before. Use @CoryKramers answer, which will do what you want in just one line

Comment: Yes I see now how list of lists iterate. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` in a dict comprehension

```
>>> {idx: sublist for idx, sublist in enumerate(AST, 1)}
{1: ['AGENDA'],
 2: ["WOMEN'S STATUS", 'TREATIES', 'SIGNATURES, ACCESSIONS, RATIFICATIONS', 'RESERVATIONS AND DECLARATIONS', 'GENDER DISCRIMINATION'],
 3: ['ELECTION OF MEMBERS', 'BIOGRAPHY'],
 4: ["WOMEN'S RIGHTS", "WOMEN'S STATUS", 'PERIODIC REPORTS']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this  -

```
print(dict(enumerate(AST, 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AST = ['AGENDA'],["WOMEN'S STATUS", 'TREATIES',
'SIGNATURES, ACCESSIONS, RATIFICATIONS',
'RESERVATIONS AND DECLARATIONS',
'GENDER DISCRIMINATION'], ['ELECTION OF MEMBERS',
'BIOGRAPHY'], [ "WOMEN'S RIGHTS",
"WOMEN'S STATUS",
'PERIODIC REPORTS']

dictt={}

for i in range(len(AST)):
    dictt[i+1]=AST[i]
```